# Adding tag report to sql database

Tags: c#

Hi Am quite new to c# I simply need to get the tag report from the reader and save it to a sql database

The code is:-

```
 static void OnTagsReported(ImpinjReader sender, TagReport report)
 {
      // This event handler is called asynchronously 
      // when tag reports are available.
      // Loop through each tag in the report 
      // and print the data.
      foreach (Tag tag in report)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("EPCtags : {0} ", tag.Epc);
      }
 }
```

Got this now but cannot access the tag as a value for the parameter

```
 static void OnTagsReported(ImpinjReader sender, TagReport report)
    {

       var connection = new SqlConnection();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TagRead (Reader,EpcTag,Date) VALUES (@Reader, @EpcTag, @Date,)", connection);

    foreach (Tag tag in report)


             cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reader", SqlDbType.NChar);
             cmd.Parameters["@EPCTag"].Value = Tag;



            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

}

This allows me to access the "tag" variable but only for one parameter. Not sure why this is happening?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TagRead (Reader,EpcTag,Date) VALUES (@Reader, @EpcTag, @Date,)", connection);

    foreach (Tag tag in report)


             cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reader", SqlDbType.NChar).Value=tag.Epc;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@EpcTag", SqlDbType.NChar).Value=tag;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=tag;






            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: If you're using `SQL Server` you can use a `SqlConnection` and a `SqlCommand` object to connect to/update the database.  A quick google search will give you an example of how to do so.

Comment: with sqlcommand would you simply use the INSERT statement and add the varibles. I need this to then display on at datagrid after the tags have been read.

Comment: yes, you could use the `INSERT` statement or use a stored procedure. I would also recommend using paramerterized statements when using the `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: Ive got this so far but dont seem to be able to access the tag data

Comment: If you provide code in your question, state what does not work about it or how it does not function as expected. I'm not seeing you setting a value for your `@Date` parameter, so that could be a problem.

Comment: So basically instead of writing to the console I need to save the tags to a database.